# adding two values from different classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, math, integer

```
class PolygonInteriorAngle(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = self
    
    def FindInteriorAngle(self):
        degrees = int((x - 2) * 180)
        interior = int(degrees / x)
        return interior
    
    def PrintInterior(self):
        print("interior angle: " + str(self.FindInteriorAngle()))

class PolygonExteriorAngle(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = self
    
    def FindExteriorAngle(self):
        exterior = int(360 / x)
        return exterior
    
    def PrintExterior(self):
        print("exterior angle: " + str(self.FindExteriorAngle()))

class AngleAddition(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = self
    
    def Add(self):
        sum = int(interior + exterior)
        return sum
    
    def PrintAdd(self):
        print("sum of interior and exterior: " + str(self.Add()))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = int(input("enter: "))
    intObj = PolygonInteriorAngle(x)
    intObj.FindInteriorAngle()
    intObj.PrintInterior()
    extObj = PolygonExteriorAngle(x)
    extObj.FindExteriorAngle()
    extObj.PrintExterior()
    addObj = AngleAddition(x)
    addObj.Add()
    addObj.PrintAdd()
```

both classes (PolygonInteriorAngle and PolygonExteriorAngle) work fine, they print what they're expected to. what i want to do in the AngleAddition class is to add both of the final values (interior and exterior) that you get from the other two classes. i think it's pretty inefficient putting them in different classes, but that's what my computer science teacher asked me to and i'm not sure how to use a value from another class in a new class. if you do x = 6, you'll get 120 and 60. with AngleAddition i want to print 180.

Comment: Those should not be classes.  You might have a class called "Angle" and have these things be methods in that class, or a class called "Polygon" that starts with a number of sides and returned exterior and interior angle, but it's pointless to have separate classes for interior angles and exterior angles, when one is directly derived from the other.

Comment: Agree with @TimRoberts. If you still insist on doing something like that, you can check out staticmethod decorator. You can use it as a getter for interior and exterior final. Then you'd have `add_final_values()` method in your `AngleAddition` class that takes two parameters to sum.

Answer (score 0):

General comments:

1. You need to check very carefully the variables in your instance methods. example:

```
    def Add(self):
        sum = int(interior + exterior)
        return sum
```

Both `interior` and `exterior` are not specified in the instance method arguments.

2. I agree with User: Tim Roberts's comment. Either you make a base class "angle" and let the "interior/exterior angle" class inherit from the "angle" class, or just use angle class for both interior/exterior angles. It depends on how you want to write the `__init__` method for interior/exterior angle classes.
3. Note that I overrode the magic method to perform the sum of two angles. There are other ways of doing that cause in my way the `+` operator is being redefined.

Anyways:

```
class AngleBase:
  def __init__(self,angle):
    self.angle=angle

  def __add__(self,angleobj):
    return int(self.angle+angleobj.angle)

class PolygonInteriorAngle(AngleBase):
    def __init__(self, side):
        degrees = int((side - 2) * 180)
        interior = int(degrees / side)
        AngleBase.__init__(self,interior)
    
    def FindInteriorAngle(self):
        return self.angle
    
    def PrintInterior(self):
        print("interior angle: " + str(self.angle))

class PolygonExteriorAngle(AngleBase):
    def __init__(self, side):
        exterior = int(360 / side)
        AngleBase.__init__(self,exterior)
    
    def FindExteriorAngle(self):
        return self.angle
    
    def PrintExterior(self):
        print("exterior angle: " + str(self.angle))

class AngleAddition:
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass
    
    def Add(self,interior, exterior):
        sum = int(interior + exterior)
        return sum
    
    def PrintAdd(self,interior, exterior):
        print("sum of interior and exterior: " + str(self.Add(interior, exterior)))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = int(input("enter: "))
    intObj = PolygonInteriorAngle(x)
    print(intObj.angle)
    intObj.FindInteriorAngle()
    intObj.PrintInterior()
    extObj = PolygonExteriorAngle(x)
    extObj.FindExteriorAngle()
    extObj.PrintExterior()
    addObj = AngleAddition(x)
    addObj.Add(extObj,intObj)
    addObj.PrintAdd(extObj,intObj)
```